# JPA does not add Id to database from wrapping object

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, insert, entitymanager

Using JPA I have a dataconfiguration, which is added to the database with no problems:

```
   @Entity @Table(name = "dataConfigurations", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"})})
    @NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "DataConfigurations.names", query = "SELECT d.name FROM DataConfiguration d"), @NamedQuery(name = "DataConfiguration.findByName", query = "SELECT d FROM DataConfiguration d WHERE d.name = :name")})
    public class DataConfiguration implements Serializable
    {

        @Transient
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.)
            //@TableGenerator(name = "dataConfigurationSequence", table = "Sequences", pkColumnName = "NameSequences", valueColumnName = "valueSequence", pkColumnValue = "dataConfigurationId")
        private long id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataConfiguration", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Content> contents; // "Data" is a reserved SQL word.
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "dataConfigurations", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<LabelType> labelTypes;
        private String name;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataConfiguration", cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        private List<Template> templates;
```

This Dataconfiguration contains a list of Contents (one to many relationship),
the other mappings (templates en labelTypes do not matter for now but will later on in my program, they will probably give me the same problem as I have with contents)

```
@Entity @Table(name = "contents", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"dataConfigurationId", "displayOrder"})})
    public class Content implements Serializable
    {
        @Transient
        private static transient final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            //@TableGenerator(name = "contentSequence", table = "Sequences", pkColumnName = "NameSequences", valueColumnName = "valueSequence", pkColumnValue = "contentId")
        private long id;
        private String content; // "Data" is a reserved word in traditional SQL.
            @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "dataConfigurationId")
        private DataConfiguration dataConfiguration;
        private int displayOrder;
        private int editableFrom;
        private String typeDiscriminator;
```

This is the controller method that initiates the save method:

```
public String saveDataConfiguration()
{
    dataConfiguration = new DataConfiguration(getNextId(), dataConfigurationName, contents);
    dataConfigurationFacade.create(dataConfiguration);
    return null;
}
```

The create method is part of the AbstractFacade

```
public void create(T entity)
{
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        getEntityManager().flush();
}
```

When I execute the method everything except the Id of the dataconfiguration in the content table is saved.
(Foreign key of the dataconfiguration is not saved in content)
Any hints and/or tips would very helpful!

Comment: I managed to avoid the problem by using the entitymanager's NativeQuery but I would still like to know what went wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to initialize the field `dataConfiguration` of every content. That's the one which is mapped to the join column, and it's thus the one that Hibernate inspects to determine if there is an association between the two entities or not.